# Cannot use MenuItemColors.copy()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

The [docs for material3 MenuItemColors](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/MenuItemColors#copy) refers to a public `copy()` method, but in AS I get "unresolved reference", and there is no
extension function to import:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.MenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MenuItemColors

@Composable 
fun CantCopyColors () {
    val mic = MenuDefaults.itemColors() // Returns MenuItemColors
    val copy = mic.copy()
                // ^^^^ Error
}
```

This happens with a newly constructed object as well as the `itemColors()` default (ie., calling `.copy()` on the object it returns, as above, and not using parameters to `itemColors()` instead).

Happens in both AS Hedgehog 2032.1.1 and JellyFish 2023.3.1 (Canary 4) using material3 1.2.0-beta01
(beta02 gives me some insurmountable `IncompatibleClassChangeErrors`).

Is this a just plain bug or is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Menu.kt;drc=b0cfb0f7a270c6f74bd64d6e9a32f85fb4770495) it seems like the copy function should be present. I don't know why it does not appear to work, but from the source code, it seems like you can also pass your wished overrides of colors directly to the `itemColors()` function.

```
@Composable
fun itemColors(
    textColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    leadingIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    trailingIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    disabledTextColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    disabledLeadingIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    disabledTrailingIconColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
): MenuItemColors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.defaultMenuItemColors.copy(
    textColor = textColor,
    leadingIconColor = leadingIconColor,
    trailingIconColor = trailingIconColor,
    disabledTextColor = disabledTextColor,
    disabledLeadingIconColor = disabledLeadingIconColor,
    disabledTrailingIconColor = disabledTrailingIconColor,
)
```

So instead of

```
val mic = MenuDefaults.itemColors() // Returns MenuItemColors
val copy = mic.copy(textColor = Color.Red)
```

try to do it as follows:

```
val mic = MenuDefaults.itemColors(textColor = Color.Red)
```

Please consider to open a ticket on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) about this strange case and link the issue here.

Comment: Using `itemColors()` that way does work.  I've reported the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/321581214, although first I tried it with `-beta02` and there is not a problem there (and fortunately the runtime `IncompatibleClassChangeError`  I had from `ExposedDropDownMenu` seems to have disappeared), so I don't know if this matters much.

Comment: Do I understand that right, the `copy` function is now available and everything works as it should in beta-02? Then they might already have resolved the issue in the past, and yes, the issue will then be redundant.

Comment: You understand correctly!